# Prolog Rules Reflect Strucutre

Tags: prolog, structure, rule

i need to design a rules which test a loan is a car loan or not.

```
carLoan(flexiCar,minLoanAmount(20000),maxTenure(12) ).
iscarloan(X, Y, Z) :- carLoan(X, Y >= minLoanAmount(20000), Z =<(maxTenure(12)) ).
iscarloan(X, 25000, 10).
```

I need to test the Y and Z variable against the structure from the fact inside the rule.

How to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iscarloan(X, Y, Z) :-
  carLoan(X, minLoanAmount(MinLoan), maxTenure(MaxTenure)),
  Y >= MinLoan,
  Z =< MaxTenure.
```

It that what you had in mind?

Comment: I tested the rules using some queries and it shows error which point out that minLoanAmount is not a function.

Comment: Error message is
ERROR: >= /2 Arithmetic minLoanAmount is not a function

Comment: My bad - I fixed the matching on the 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

```
carLoan(flexiCar, minLoanAmount(20000), maxTenure(12)).

iscarloan(X, Y, Z) :-
    Y = minLoanAmount(MLA),
    Z = maxTenure(MT),
    MLAN is MLA,
    MTN is MT,
    MLAN >= 20000,
    MTN =< 12.

iscarloan(X, 25000, 10).
```

Comment: I got the answers as follow. 
isguarantor(X,Y) :- guarantor(X,Y), notCustomer(X).
iscarloan(LoanType, Y, Z) 
 :- carLoan(LoanType, minLoanAmount(MLA), maxTenure(MT)),
 Y >= MLA, Z =< MT.